# How to search on struct char c?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>  //libraries
#include<string.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 4 //define the array size is 4
```

**Declare a Person structure containing the following two data members: name and age.**

```
 struct Person
{
 char name[20];
 int age;
};
```

**Define fillPersons function that takes an empty array of Persons, and fills the array.**

```
 void fillPersons(struct Person * myPs);
```

**For function using**

```
 struct Person p[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

**Define searchPerson function that takes an array of Persons, and the name to search for. The function will return the corresponding age if the person is found, -1 otherwise.**

```
int searchPerson(struct Person * myPs, char * myName);
```

**Define printPersons function that takes an array of Persons, and prints the content of the array.**

```
void printPersons(struct Person * myPs);
```

Main Fuction

```
int main()
{
struct Person p[ARRAY_SIZE];
int a;
int isFound;
char myName[20];
```

**Switch case for user interface**

```
do
{
    printf("1)FILL ARRAY\n");
    printf("2)SEARCH BY NAME\n");
    printf("3)PRINT ARRAY\n");
    printf("4)EXIT\n");
    printf("Search Operation:");

    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:fillPersons(p); break;
```

**I write the main part of searching but i cant fill the function.**

```
    case 2:printf("\Give the name to search for:");
        scanf_s("%s", &myName);
        isFound = searchPerson(p, myName);
        if (isFound == -1)
        {
            printf("%s not avaible in the array. \n", myName);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The age of %s is %d.\n", myName, isFound);
        }
        break;
```

**After this part it is okay to read names and ages but cant do it searching part.**

```
    case 3:printPersons(p); break; 
    case 4:printf("\nProgram exits ..."); exit(0);
    }
} while (a != 4);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

**It is okay this scanf part**

```
void fillPersons(struct Person * myPs)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)//defining 4 person i<4
    {
        scanf_s("%20s", p[i].name,_countof(p[i].name));//if i dont do _coutof 
        scanf_s("%d", &p[i].age);                      // i get null.ptr error 
    }                                                  //  on visiual studio   
}
```

**Printing the student names and ages**

```
void printPersons(struct Person * myPs)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d", p[i].name, p[i].age);
    }
}
```

**But i dont know how to fill with inside on fuction?**

```
  int searchPerson(struct Person * myPs, char * myName)
```

**THE OUTPUT SHOULD BE LIKE THIS**

[image: output]

Comment: First things first, compile your program, find and fix all the errors. Specifically, you call functions with `*myPs` but you access `p[i].`variable.  So, the rule of SO is that you must post a [mcve] and if you can't get it to compile, point out what errors you get when you try to compile.

Comment: One more thing, `scanf_s("%s", &myName);` is not ideal (use fgets instead).  Regardless, the call should be `scanf_s("%s", myName);`

Comment: If you were sold a C++ course, you need to be informed that the course was missold.

Comment: @KevinDTimm when i compile it without the search function i get no error.

Comment: @KevinDTimm  thnx for scanf :)

Comment: Then you didn't post your actual code.  Variable `p` is defined in `main` but you're accessing it in `fill` and `print` functions - guaranteed to create an error in every compiler I've ever encountered.

Comment: @KevinDTimm thnx for that i edited

Comment: Please post a [mcve] because what you've posted cannot possibly compile.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I can compile in online c compiler

Comment: I will repeat : you cannot compile the code above anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the function you are missing is `strcmp` to compare two strings.

It could be like:

```
int searchPerson(struct Person * myPs, char * myName)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(myPs[i].name, myName) == 0)
        {
            return myPs[i].age;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

In general notice:

When you pass the array to a function as `struct Person * myPs`, you must use `myPs` inside the function. Further you should use the defined array size instead of hard coding a `4`.

So your `printPersons` should be:

```
void printPersons(struct Person * myPs)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d", myPs[i].name, myPs[i].age);
    }
}
```

Same applies to `fillPersons`

Comment: After using this as my fuction i get the error of couldn't find the name of

Comment: @BatuhanGöbekli - did you fix the scanf problem? `scanf_s("%s", &myName);` -> `scanf_s("%s", myName);`

Comment: @ 4386427 help me please

Comment: @BatuhanGöbekli - Don't know what you mean by `i get the error of couldn't find the name of ` ! The name of what? Compile time error or run time error ?

Comment: when i write a name after that on searching i get  the else part " not avaible in array "

Comment: @ 4386427 on the up

Comment: @BatuhanGöbekli - 1) Did you fix the scanf bug? 2) Did you fix `fillPersons` function? 3) Did you check that `fillPersons`works? By inserting a person and the printing it...

Comment: @BatuhanGöbekli - You have all rights to unaccept an answer - no problem - I'm just curious here. What made you unaccept the answer more than 1 year after it was accepted?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you put in your question all the functions except the one that is giving you problems: `searchPerson`.
Then, your error is with this instruction:

> scanf_s("%s", &myName);

Accordingly that you declared `myName` as a char pointer, this way, you're assigning the string to the address of `myName`, not to the memory cells it's pointing to.

Instead, this should be:

```
scanf_s("%s", myName);
```